# First time deploy and I've no idea why it doesnt work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I wrote an example app which is just a react survey app that doesnt really do anything atm other than you fill it out and after you submit, it prints to the console. I've pretty new to web development, I've been more of a backend programmer all of my life. Thought Id give heroku a go so I'm completely lost as to why it doesnt work as when I run it locally it works?

Link to app

https://survey-app-heroku.herokuapp.com/

Error from heroku

```
2021-04-01T09:31:29.452833+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-04-01T09:31:38.073017+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-04-01T09:31:40.947621+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-01T09:31:40.947674+00:00 app[web.1]: > survey-app@0.1.0 start /app
2021-04-01T09:31:40.947675+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start        
2021-04-01T09:31:40.947675+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-01T09:31:44.889614+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-01T09:31:44.647987+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.147.66/
2021-04-01T09:31:44.648360+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2021-04-01T09:31:44.648445+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2021-04-01T09:31:44.648520+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2021-04-01T09:31:44.649232+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2021-04-01T09:31:44.649233+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-01T09:32:01.243403+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-01T09:32:01.243415+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- Last few GCs --->
2021-04-01T09:32:01.243415+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-01T09:32:01.243437+00:00 app[web.1]: [28:0x5ff50a0]    19672 ms: Scavenge 253.3 (257.4) -> 253.1 (257.9) MB, 1.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.649, current mu = 0.498) allocation failure
2021-04-01T09:32:01.243438+00:00 app[web.1]: [28:0x5ff50a0]    19865 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 253.6 (257.9) -> 252.4 (258.2) MB, 160.1 / 0.0 ms  (+ 27.0 ms in 7 steps since start of marking, biggest step 8.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 193 ms) (average mu = 0.515, current mu = 0.260) allocati
2021-04-01T09:32:01.243438+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-01T09:32:01.243439+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
2021-04-01T09:32:01.243439+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-01T09:32:01.243453+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2021-04-01T09:32:01.245099+00:00 app[web.1]: 1: 0xa04200 node::Abort() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.245577+00:00 app[web.1]: 2: 0x94e4e9 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.246067+00:00 app[web.1]: 3: 0xb7978e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.246543+00:00 app[web.1]: 4: 0xb79b07 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.247180+00:00 app[web.1]: 5: 0xd34395  [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.247761+00:00 app[web.1]: 6: 0xd64f2e v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor::Visit(v8::internal::HeapObject, int) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.248350+00:00 app[web.1]: 7: 0xd70f66 v8::internal::FullEvacuator::RawEvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*, long*) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.249018+00:00 app[web.1]: 8: 0xd5d14f v8::internal::Evacuator::EvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.249510+00:00 app[web.1]: 9: 0xd5d3c8 v8::internal::PageEvacuationTask::RunInParallel(v8::internal::ItemParallelJob::Task::Runner) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.250061+00:00 app[web.1]: 10: 0xd4fca9 v8::internal::ItemParallelJob::Run() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.250648+00:00 app[web.1]: 11: 0xd72ec0 void v8::internal::MarkCompactCollectorBase::CreateAndExecuteEvacuationTasks<v8::internal::FullEvacuator, v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector>(v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector*, v8::internal::ItemParallelJob*, v8::internal::MigrationObserver*, long) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.251199+00:00 app[web.1]: 12: 0xd7375c v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuatePagesInParallel() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.251761+00:00 app[web.1]: 13: 0xd73925 v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuate() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.252345+00:00 app[web.1]: 14: 0xd85911 v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.252894+00:00 app[web.1]: 15: 0xd41c38 v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.253476+00:00 app[web.1]: 16: 0xd43728 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.254026+00:00 app[web.1]: 17: 0xd46b6c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.254579+00:00 app[web.1]: 18: 0xd1524b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.255216+00:00 app[web.1]: 19: 0x105b23f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.255921+00:00 app[web.1]: 20: 0x1401219  [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:01.299741+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-04-01T09:32:01.300094+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-04-01T09:32:01.304998+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! survey-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
2021-04-01T09:32:01.305103+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-04-01T09:32:01.305248+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-04-01T09:32:01.305340+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the survey-app@0.1.0 start script.
2021-04-01T09:32:01.305423+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-04-01T09:32:01.312350+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-01T09:32:01.312518+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-04-01T09:32:01.312625+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-04-01T09_32_01_306Z-debug.log
2021-04-01T09:32:01.363370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-01T09:32:01.422171+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-04-01T09:32:01.431820+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-04-01T09:32:09.852169+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-04-01T09:32:13.991949+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-01T09:32:13.991975+00:00 app[web.1]: > survey-app@0.1.0 start /app
2021-04-01T09:32:13.991975+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2021-04-01T09:32:13.991976+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-01T09:32:19.518845+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-04-01T09:32:19.450334+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.16.72.106/
2021-04-01T09:32:19.450906+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2021-04-01T09:32:19.451033+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2021-04-01T09:32:19.451125+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2021-04-01T09:32:19.452046+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2021-04-01T09:32:19.452048+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-01T09:32:33.627383+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-04-01T09:32:33.627396+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- Last few GCs --->
2021-04-01T09:32:33.627396+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-01T09:32:33.627400+00:00 app[web.1]: [28:0x5a290a0]    18845 ms: Scavenge 252.5 (256.9) -> 252.4 (257.4) MB, 4.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.645, current mu = 0.547) allocation failure
2021-04-01T09:32:33.627401+00:00 app[web.1]: [28:0x5a290a0]    18856 ms: Scavenge 253.1 (257.4) -> 252.9 (257.7) MB, 1.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.645, current mu = 0.547) allocation failure
2021-04-01T09:32:33.627401+00:00 app[web.1]: [28:0x5a290a0]    19073 ms: Mark-sweep 253.4 (257.7) -> 251.8 (258.2) MB, 208.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.486, current mu = 0.234) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed    
2021-04-01T09:32:33.627402+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-01T09:32:33.627402+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-01T09:32:33.627402+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
2021-04-01T09:32:33.627402+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-01T09:32:33.627408+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2021-04-01T09:32:33.628046+00:00 app[web.1]: 1: 0xa04200 node::Abort() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.628496+00:00 app[web.1]: 2: 0x94e4e9 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.629004+00:00 app[web.1]: 3: 0xb7978e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.629547+00:00 app[web.1]: 4: 0xb79b07 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.630069+00:00 app[web.1]: 5: 0xd34395  [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.630643+00:00 app[web.1]: 6: 0xd64f2e v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor::Visit(v8::internal::HeapObject, int) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.631180+00:00 app[web.1]: 7: 0xd70f66 v8::internal::FullEvacuator::RawEvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*, long*) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.631758+00:00 app[web.1]: 8: 0xd5d14f v8::internal::Evacuator::EvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.632335+00:00 app[web.1]: 9: 0xd5d3c8 v8::internal::PageEvacuationTask::RunInParallel(v8::internal::ItemParallelJob::Task::Runner) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.632908+00:00 app[web.1]: 10: 0xd4fca9 v8::internal::ItemParallelJob::Run() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.633507+00:00 app[web.1]: 11: 0xd72ec0 void v8::internal::MarkCompactCollectorBase::CreateAndExecuteEvacuationTasks<v8::internal::FullEvacuator, v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector>(v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector*, v8::internal::ItemParallelJob*, v8::internal::MigrationObserver*, long) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.634061+00:00 app[web.1]: 12: 0xd7375c v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuatePagesInParallel() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.634638+00:00 app[web.1]: 13: 0xd73925 v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuate() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.635203+00:00 app[web.1]: 14: 0xd85911 v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.635770+00:00 app[web.1]: 15: 0xd41c38 v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.636331+00:00 app[web.1]: 16: 0xd43728 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.636893+00:00 app[web.1]: 17: 0xd46b6c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.637474+00:00 app[web.1]: 18: 0xd1524b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.638125+00:00 app[web.1]: 19: 0x105b23f v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.638869+00:00 app[web.1]: 20: 0x1401219  [/app/.heroku/node/bin/node]
2021-04-01T09:32:33.681562+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-04-01T09:32:33.681983+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-04-01T09:32:33.688061+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! survey-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
2021-04-01T09:32:33.688226+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-04-01T09:32:33.688411+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-04-01T09:32:33.688573+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the survey-app@0.1.0 start script.
2021-04-01T09:32:33.688704+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-04-01T09:32:33.697140+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-04-01T09:32:33.697357+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-04-01T09:32:33.697502+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-04-01T09_32_33_689Z-debug.log
2021-04-01T09:32:33.755358+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-04-01T09:32:33.843501+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-04-01T09:32:33.666270+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=survey-app-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=6d8cc236-62ec-43f8-8044-2e6808aa48c8 fwd="92.2.137.222" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=13715ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-04-01T09:32:38.809025+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=survey-app-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=91f9b332-4645-41ad-a8cd-8650e35e5b45 fwd="92.2.137.222" dyno=web.1 connect=5000ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Is what I'm doing even possible/ I was hoping to write this app for my local club to use for covid regulations

Thanks!

Comment: `FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`, looks like your app needs some more memory

Comment: @MathieuLescaudron Ahh thanks alot man!

Answer (score 0):

it is node error, in your package.json. you need to add in you deployment script

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 fileName.js
```

which tells to node what part of RAM use for this project

Comment: I tried that and Im getting this now

> survey-app@0.1.0 start C:\Users\robert.tuppen\Documents\dev\survey-app-heroku
> node --max-old-space-size=4096 src/app.js

C:\Users\[user dir]\Documents\dev\survey-app-heroku\src\app.js:1
import './App.css';
       ^^^^^^^^^^^


This is a react app btw if it makes a difference